# Linq statement with 2 joins a where and need a count

Tags: c#, linq, join, count, where-clause

**This is what i have:**

```
var count = (from p in _db.Personen
                        join pc in _db.Postcodes on p.Postcode equals pc.postcode
                        join r in _db.Regios on pc.RegioId equals r.RegioId
                        where (p.Leeftijd >= leeftijdgetal[0] && leeftijd[1] <= p.Leeftijd) &&
                        r.RegioNaam == regio && p.Geslacht == geslacht
                        select new
                        {
                            teller = Where(p => p.Showit == 1).Count()
                        }).Distinct();
```

It gives an error on teller.
How can i recieve a number of all the persons between 2 ages with that specifiek region and a specifiek gender.

the tables are as followed:

**Personen:**

-PersoonId

-Naam
-Voornaam
-Leeftijd
-Geslacht
-Adres
-Postcode
-Telefoon
-Email
-Wachtwoord
-RollId
-VragenlijstId
-Status
-MantelverzorgerId
-DokterId
-eID

**Postcodes:**

-Postcode
-Gemeente
-RegioId
-PostcodeId

**Regios:**

-RegioId
-RegioNaam

Comment: It fails on `teller` because `Where(p => p.Showit == 1).Count()` is invalid syntax, `Where` needs to be called on an enumerable (which it isn't here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you don't need a projection at all here

```
var count = (from p in _db.Personen
             join pc in _db.Postcodes on p.Postcode equals pc.postcode
             join r in _db.Regios on pc.RegioId equals r.RegioId
             where p.Leeftijd >= leeftijdgetal[0] && leeftijd[1] <= p.Leeftijd && 
                   r.RegioNaam == regio && 
                   p.Geslacht == geslacht &&
                   p.Showit == 1
            )
            .Distinct()
            .Count();
```